# show() not working to display previously hidden fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to hide/show fragments depending on a OnClickListener. Hiding a fragment works but when I want to show it again it won't show up. I don't want to use replace() because the fragment takes a while to load up since it downloads images from a server.

Here is the code of my replace method:

```
private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (addedFragments.size() != 0) {
        for (Fragment frag :
                addedFragments) {
            if (frag !=null) {
                String fragTag = frag.getClass().getName();
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragTag).isVisible() && !fragTag.equals(backStateName)) {
                    fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(frag.getClass().getName()));
                    Log.d("frag", "hide" + fragTag);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) != null && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName).isAdded()) {
        //if the fragment exists, show it.
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out).show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName)).commit();
        Log.d("frag", "show frag"+fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName).getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

And the code of the listener:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.option1) {

            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(WantedAnimals.class.getName()) == null){
                WantedAnimals wantedAnimals = new WantedAnimals();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_fragment, wantedAnimals, wantedAnimals.getClass().getName()).commit();
                addedFragments.add(wantedAnimals);
            }   else {
                replaceFragment(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(WantedAnimals.class.getName()));
            }
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.option2) {
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FoundAnimals.class.getName()) == null){
                FoundAnimals foundAnimals = new FoundAnimals();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_fragment, foundAnimals, foundAnimals.getClass().getName()).commit();
                addedFragments.add(foundAnimals);
            }   else {
                replaceFragment(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FoundAnimals.class.getName()));
            }
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.option3) {
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AnimalsToGiveAway.class.getName()) == null){
                AnimalsToGiveAway animalsToGiveAway = new AnimalsToGiveAway();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_fragment, animalsToGiveAway, animalsToGiveAway.getClass().getName()).commit();
                addedFragments.add(animalsToGiveAway);
            }   else {
                replaceFragment(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AnimalsToGiveAway.class.getName()));
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im stupid I had an old code snipped in the on create method of the fragments which removed all views if the container isn't empty lol